# Split pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sample dataframe of company A's electronic consumption shown below

| year-month | company | GWh |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-01 | A | 100 |
| 2018-02 | A | 110 |
| 2019-01 | A | 90 |
| 2019-02 | A | 105 |
| 2020-01 | A | 117 |
| 2020-02 | A | 120 |

i would like to remove data of year 2020 and split the remaining dataframe into two sets:

1. Train dataset contains records before year 2019
2. Test dataset contains only 2019 records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coerce them into datetime and select as required. This is most preferable if you'll need to use them for time analysis

```
df['year-month']=pd.to_datetime(df['year-month']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
df1=df[df['year-month'].lt('2019')]
df2=df[df['year-month'].eq('2019')]
```

Following your comment, I believe thats a bug. I would edit it to

```
df['year-month']=pd.to_datetime(df['year-month'])
df1=df[df['year-month'].dt.strftime('%Y').lt('2019')]
df2=df[df['year-month'].dt.strftime('%Y').eq('2019')]
```

Comment: Hi somehow there isn't any data for df2. My df1 is working perfectly though. Is there any reason why?

Comment: You are right, and that to me looks like a bug.

Comment: Ahh okay so its not just me. Is there anyway to fix this, as i feel the code is great

Comment: The following three lines can achieve the same , keeping the year column intact. `df = df.assign(year_month =pd.to_datetime(df['year-month']).dt.strftime('%Y_%m'), year=pd.to_datetime(df['year-month']).dt.strftime('%Y'))` and then `df1=df[df['year'].lt('2019')]` also
`df2=df[df['year'].eq('2019')]`

Comment: Maybe change your column 'year-month' to 'year_month' because '-` causes problems in columns

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`Series.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html), [`Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) and [`Series.lt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html):

```
In [358]: df1 = df[df['year-month'].str.split('-').str[0].astype(int).lt(2019)]

In [359]: df2 = df[df['year-month'].str.split('-').str[0].astype(int).eq(2019)]

In [360]: df1
Out[360]: 
  year-month company  GWh
0    2017-01       A  100
1    2018-02       A  110

In [361]: df2
Out[361]: 
  year-month company  GWh
2    2019-01       A   90
3    2019-02       A  105
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the dataset is a time or date-ordered event log, you can use a time-sensitive cross-validation splitter **TimeSeriesSplit()**

```
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit

ts_cv = TimeSeriesSplit(
    n_splits=1,
    max_train_size=10000, # Here enter the count of records for years before 2019
    test_size=1000, #Here enter the count of records in 2019
)
```

To manually inspect the split to check that the TimeSeriesSplit worked as we expect.

```
train, test = list(ts_cv.split(X, y))
X.iloc[test]
X.iloc[train]
```